# BLANK VALUE IN SSRS BUT DATA IN SQL QUERY

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I'm working in a solution in SSRS that it's driving me crazy, I will explain it a bit before shows you my problem:

Select 25 data values from a table with analog input data (from current, voltage, pressure, etc. tags) using parameters @startDate = yeterday 6am and @EndDate = today 6am. Now we have a table with 25 values from 6am to 6am from different tagID's.

My problem starts when just one tagId of 16, it's showing me in the SSRS presentation values 0.0000 when in the Sql output shows me -0.00548...
For practical purpouses I will just use 2 tagIds (MSF_PDI_003, MSF_PDI_004)

Here the SQL Query:

```
declare @startDate  datetime2 = '2017-04-19 11:00',
        @endDate    datetime2 = '2017-04-20 11:00';

SELECT InstaTime,
    MSF_PDI_003,
    MSF_PDI_004
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(HH,-5,H.time) AS InstaTime,
        SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN t.tagName = 'analog.MSF_PDI_003.curval'
                    Then H.value
                ELSE 0
            END) as MSF_PDI_003,
        SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN t.tagName = 'analog.MSF_PDI_004.curval'
                    Then H.value
                ELSE 0
            END) as MSF_PDI_004
    FROM hour H
    INNER JOIN tag T 
        ON T.tagId = H.tagId 
    WHERE T.tagName IN 
        ('analog.MSF_PDI_003.curval', 'analog.MSF_PDI_004.curval')
        AND H.time >= @startDate
        And H.time <= @endDate

  GROUP BY time
    ) QueryData

order by InstaTime desc
```

And this the result of the query:

[SQL QUERY RESULT IN SQL-SERVER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOsfM.png)

And these are the expressions that I'm using in the textboxes of the tablix in the SSRS (I used a test dataset for this query: summary_prueba)

```
=Fields!InstaTime.Value         
=Fields!MSF_PDI_003.Value           
=Fields!MSF_PDI_004.Value
```

And here the results of the table in SSRS:

[CLICK IMAGE: SAMPLE2 SRSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSLcb.png)

What could be the problem around here? 
 * Is the Only one with negative values, could be forcing a round? Something about a different format I should use?

Driving me nuts and can't find what's wrong. I tried to change the format and is the same, can you guys please help me? Because this thing doesn't let me sleep at night, I'm starting to have nightmares lol.

I'm using SQL Server 2012, and for the report MS Visual Studio Shell 2010.

Comment: Why do you have `First` in your expression? Maybe the first value is always blank. Create a simple list report and list all of the data values without using `First`. What do you see?

Comment: Hello thanks for reply, I'm using a first, becasue for that textbox I need just the value of 6:00am of the day, so its order desc and the first day would be the 6am. I can see the result of the query and theres no blanks or nulls values.

Comment: Ok, this is the result with the new Query made by @Laughing Vergil
In sql and ssrs.

http://i.imgur.com/GET2Y0N.png 

http://i.imgur.com/iGEk2s7.png

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by consolidating your query into one statement, instead of the UNION and separate SELECT SUM(...) that you have now:

```
declare @startDate  datetime2 = '2017-04-18 11:00',
        @endDate    datetime2 = '2017-04-19 11:00';

SELECT InstaTime,
    MSF_PDI_003,
    MSF_PDI_004
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(HH,-5,H.time) AS InstaTime,
        SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN t.tagName = 'analog.MSF_PDI_003.curval'
                    Then H.value
                ELSE 0
            END) as MSF_PDI_003,
        SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN t.tagName = 'analog.MSF_PDI_004.curval'
                    Then H.value
                ELSE 0
            END) as MSF_PDI_004
    FROM hour H
    INNER JOIN tag T 
        ON T.tagId = H.tagId 
    WHERE T.tagName IN 
        ('analog.MSF_PDI_003.curval', 'analog.MSF_PDI_004.curval')
        AND H.time >= @startDate
        And H.time <= @endDate
    GROUP BY InstaTime
    ) QueryData
order by InstaTime desc
```

Now, if there is no matching 004 or 003 value, they will report as zero instead of being blank. Try this, and see whether this matches what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try it tomorrow at work as I don't have the SRSS here, That query looks much better and cleanner, The MSF_PDI_004 is the only one wich have negative decimal tho, after the query I can normaly see the ouptut in the SQL -0.0449... but when I wanted to post it in the SSRS blank textbox, all the others with the normal data.

Anyway I will try it and let you know, thanks very much!

Comment: Ok I changed the Query and the result in the SQL was the same, but in the SSRS now I can see 0.00 in all the values.
I created a new data set with that query and the results for the new one in a red square and old ones, blue square.       
[SQL] (http://i.imgur.com/GET2Y0N.png)      
[SSRS] (http://i.imgur.com/GbY992s.png)     
[SSRS FIRST] (http://i.imgur.com/oLWxFKr.png)

Comment: Hmmm. Truly bizarre. I'd like you to run a test. In the query I provided above, please change each `Then H.value` into `Then H.value * -1`, then rerun the [SSRS] process and show its output. I am looking to see if negative numbers show as zero in the MSF_PDI_003 column and positive numbers show as numbers in the MSF_PDI_004 column in SSRS.

Comment: Weird! I did the change in the SQL query as you recommend, and its showing normal negative decimals but the other still the same 0, not showing data.
[image](http://imgur.com/9jTTobs)

Comment: I created in the SQL Query a aux column what is the MSF_PDI_003 + (MSF_PDI_004) as aux, I can see the normal result in SQL SERVER, [Result](http://imgur.com/wZcJdmI) and tried to view it in the SSRS and shows me same value as MSF_PDI_003 [Result SRSS](http://imgur.com/lrFApVM.png) And the aux column is the same as MSF_PDI_003, so SQL query it's doing the correct result as I can see in SQL SERVER, but SSRS it's ignoring as MSF_PDI_004 was 0.00 what actually shows in the SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

All right I found a solution but not the problem, because I still don't understand why if in the sql server I can see data and in the QueryDesigner of SSRS I still have 0.00 values.

This is a relational DB, I use 2 tables, from the same database
DB: Timeseries
Table1: hour, from here I use value,time,tagId
Table2: tag, from here I use tagName,tagId

Both have tagId in common, but I just realized that exaclty just this signal MSF_PDI_004 it's not related to the tagName in the table tag.(Have to be an error when created that signal)

I changed the Query and instead of use the tagName I used the tagId, and everything was fine, I could see the same values in SSRS than I was seeing in the SQL SERVER.

Still I think its strange, because if the query works on SQL SERVER, why should not be transparent for the SSRS?

I hope somebody can explain me this, thank you for the ones who took time for read and help.